# How to sort person using bubble sort?

Tags: java

When I run this the text that outputs to my file looks like this [Lpeople.Person;@33909752 and I am not sure how to change it to the persons name and age

- Johnta Kamerling,34
- Nicola Tesla,33

that sorts it ascending

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                //Creates an integer arraylist peopleAge
                Person[] peopleAge = new Person[size];
                Person temp = null;

                for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    peopleAge[i] = entry[i];
                }
                //k number of passes 
                for (int k = 1; k < peopleAge.length; k++) {
                    for(int j = 0; j < peopleAge.length - 1; j++) {

                        // Compare left to right, not right to left.
                        if(peopleAge[j].getAge() > peopleAge[j + 1].getAge()) {

                            //swap peopleAge[j] with peopleAge[j+1]
                            temp = peopleAge[j];
                            peopleAge[j] = peopleAge[j + 1];
                            peopleAge[j + 1] = temp;
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(peopleAge);
                writer.write(peopleAge + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }
            System.out.println("check tempfile");
            reader.close();
            writer.close();
            return null;
    }
```

Comment: Define "I am having trouble", precisely. Also, read your compareTo method. What does `Integer.compare(this.age, person.getAge())` do? What does it mean if it returns 0? What do you conclude about the if block that follows?

Comment: You should explain what behavior you are observing and what did you expected.

Comment: **Search Stack Overflow** thoroughly before posting. Comparing strings, comparing numbers, and calculating age have been covered many many many times already on Stack Overflow. Explain how your Question is different and distinct, and not covered by the existing Questions & Answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Integer.compare()` is enough:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Person person) {
    return Integer.compare(this.age, person.getAge());
}
```

don't forget to implement `Comparable` for your class:

```
implements Comparable<Person>
```

If you have this implemented in your class, you can sort any array of `Person` objects by:

```
Arrays.sort(array);
```

Comment: Why does he have to implement the Comparable for his class in this case?

Comment: I believe he wants to sort an array of objects. How would the objects be compared?

Comment: His method that applies the sorting he wants returns a sorted array, I do not see any point implementing the Comparable

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see what exactly is your problem but here is some notice.

There is no point using the Integer.compare method AND then your if statement.

The Integer.compareTo function returns

1. A value > 0 if obj1 is greater than obj2
2. A value < 0 if obj1 is less than obj2
3. A value == 0 if obj1 is equal to obj2

So in case the result == 0 in the first place, the

```
result = this.age > person.age ? 1 : this.age < person.age ? -1 : 0;
```

will be always == 0